# CSS - Stop resizeable element from going beyond window size

Tags: css, resize

I have just notice, if you have element on the page that is resizeable (e.g. textarea)

When you resize it:

- it will allow you to resize as big as browser windows (inluding scroll bar)
- which ends up which putting resizeable corerner behind the scroll
- meaning you cannot size it down anymore

Please note that:
The windows is HTML element (some more HTML content inside). It does have a width value changing dynamically.

Please see the screens:

**Screen before resize**

[image: Screen before resize]

**Screen after resize:**

[image]

**Is there any CSS fix for this??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not specifically to keep it from being larger than the window, but you can set `max-width` in the CSS to keep it from being expanded beyond a reasonably size.

Comment: This does not work. As windows is HTML element (some more HTML content inside). It does have a width value changing dynamically.

Comment: Unfortunately unless you want to do `resize: none` or `resize: vertical`, you don't really have any options beside setting `max-width`.  You can try setting `max-width` as a percentage (as in @NewUser's suggestion), but that's going to be dependent on your DOM structure and whether or not that percentage somehow relates to the window's width.

Answer (score 0):

There are `max-width` and `max-height` properties in CSS. You might try to set a value like `90%`, which will — I guess — limit the sizes of your text area to 90% of the container.

If this isn't what you want, you might try to specify abolute values for it, eg: `800px` for the width.

Comment: This does not work. As windows is HTML element (some more HTML content inside). It does have a width value changing dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to disable the resizing

```
> textarea {
>        resize: none;  
         }
```

or

```
<textarea name="" value="" style="resize:none;"/>
```

Comment: The point is to allow it resize within window width (minus scrollbar width).